# Perl get input from user and determine the array value

Tags: perl

Some background, i am supposed to create a perl script to get input from user the value of 1 to 7 inclusive.

When when user enter 1, it should print Sunday. Small cup of tea.

When user enter 2, it should print Monday. Large cup of coffee and so on.

I can reached the end result, but the way i achieve it is not the correct way as i reduce the $number value by 1 in order to access the array first element

The correct way will be when user enter 1, without reducing the value by 1, it should be able to know it is to refer to the first element in the array.

Hope someone could shed some light to me on this.

```
        my @days = ('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');

        my %beverages = ('Sunday' => tea, 'Monday' => coffee, 'Tuesday' => tea, 'Wednesday' => coffee, 'Thursday' => tea, 'Friday' => coffee, 'Saturday' => tea );

        print "Please enter a number between 1 and 7 (inclusive) \n";
        my $number = <STDIN>;
        $number -=1;
        $which = $days[$number];
        $mod = ($number+1) % 2;


        if ($days[$number] == $name[$number])
        {
            print "$days[$number].";
            if ($mod == 0)
            {
            print "Large cup of $beverages{$which}";
            }
            else
            {
            print "Small cup of $beverages{$which}";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just use `$which = $days[$number-1]` without changing the value of `$number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your test `if ($days[$number] == $name[$number])` as there is no such array as `@name`, so I have removed it altogether

This appears to do what you ask. I have chosen to calculate the beverage, as it alternates in the same way as the size. You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` and declare all your variables with `my` at their first point of use

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @days = qw/
    Sunday
    Monday
    Tuesday
    Wednesday
    Thursday
    Friday
    Saturday
/;
my @beverages = qw/ coffee tea /;
my @sizes     = qw/ Large Small /;

print "Please enter a number between 1 and 7 (inclusive): ";
chomp( my $number = <STDIN> );

my $dayname = $days[$number-1];
my $drink   = $beverages[$number % 2];
my $size    = $sizes[$number % 2];

print "$dayname. $size cup of $drink\n"
```